# How to load a PEAR package

Tags: php, installation, package, pear

I've just installed a `PEAR` package (`Event_Dispatcher`) and I can't use the classes in that package. When I run the command `pear list` I see the new package, however I see that the classes in the package are saved in `/usr/lib/php` (I have a Mac).

Is there a loading part after installing a `PEAR` package? How exactly do I move the files to the right place? Can I simply cut and paste the folder to the `pear` root folder?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Most PEAR packages have to be included via the usual `include()` and `require()` functions. They're not precompiled binaries, like (say) the MySQL driver (mysql.so/mysql.dll) are. As long as `/usr/lib/php` is in your include_path, PHP should be able to load up the package automatically when you do `include('nameofpackage.php')`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That might work, the only thing is I need to have the package in a specific folder, so I can roll out the code to production with the new classes included. I'm not using the PEAR classes only locally.

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't just install those PEAR packages onto the production server as well?

Answer (score 1):

When PEAR is installed it usually automagically configures your php.ini to add the PEAR library path to the php.ini. Then, for each package, the authors will usually provide a file that will load the library for you which sits in the root of this PEAR lib directory.

For example, a PEAR package MDB2 has a load of different classes located under /MDB2, but there's also a PHP script at /MDB2.php, so all you need to do from your PHP code is this:

```
require_once("MDB2.php").
```

You'll obviously need to keep track of what you have installed on your local dev machine and make sure it's installed on the production server(s) too.